# Rider: Docker-compose configuration won't open web page after launch

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, rider

Using Jetbrains Rider IDE to run an asp.net7 project with docker-compose on ubuntu 22.10.

All works well, except for a minor annoyance: when docker-compose is up, I have to open a web browser and navigate to the url. Jetbrains won't open the page for me once successfully launched the web app.

Is there a trick which fixes that ?

[image]

Of course I don't want to open the browser **before** launch, but regardless, it doesn't work anyway :). I tried both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Have you tried both _Multirun_ and _Compound_ configuration?

Comment: Any solutions to this? I'm in the same situation